# Почему после установки PostgreSQL я не могу запустить SQL shell?

Tags: java, postgresql

[image]

Вот такую фигню получаю, при том у меня установка нормально проходит, сносил и ставил заново - так же. Нужны базы в дальнейшем для языка Java. Прохожу по простейшим мануалам и получаю вот такое. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А телнет соединяется с указанным портом? файрвольчик проверьте...

Comment: БД явно не работает на localhost:5432, в службах запущена? Возможно стоит посмотреть в другом направлении - развернуть БД через docker например)